# Dependency between ACM certificate and CloudFront distribution modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I'm using a couple of modules in my Terraform configuration: `acm_certificate` and `cloudfront_distribution`. I want to create the CloudFront distribution only when the certificate has been validated. For some reasons, certificate must be validated manually.

```
module "acm_certificate" {
  //params
}

module "cloudfront_distribution" {
  //params
}
```

Currently, I proceed this way:

1. Plan/apply certificate with `-target=module.acm_certificate`
2. Validate certificate
3. Run full plan/apply. Here, CloudFront distribution is created

Is it possible to change the config so I just have to run two full plan/apply without `-target`?

I tried this:

```
module "acm_certificate" {
  //params
}

module "cloudfront_distribution" {
  //params

  count  = module.acm_certificate.status == "PENDING_VALIDATION" ? 0 : 1
  depends_on = [module.acm_certificate]
}
```

But I got this error:

> The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be
> determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances
> will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to
> first apply only the resources that the count depends on.

It seems `depends_on` does not work as I expected. Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: I would argue that both `count` and `depends_on` work as expected, but they cannot be used in the way you are trying to do. Also, since there are manual steps involved, that kind of defeats the purpose of IaC. So you might even consider creating the certificate outside of terraform and then using a data source to fetch it. Alternatively, you could consider introducing this into your code: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep.